# unexpected keyword argument 'type' for bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gcloud

So i am trying to follow this example :
http://ajkannan.github.io/gcloud-python/latest/bigquery-usage.html

But when i try to create a table :

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
from gcloud.bigquery import SchemaField
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "toto.json"
os.environ['GCLOUD_PROJECT'] = 'titi'
from gcloud import pubsub

client = pubsub.Client('titi')

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Instantiates a client
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

# The name for the new dataset
dataset_name = 'tata'

dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
table = dataset.table(name='aspire_page')

table.schema = [
     SchemaField(name= 'id', type= 'int', mode= 'nullable'),
     SchemaField(name= 'zip', type= 'string', mode= 'nullable'),
     SchemaField(name= 'html', type= 'string', mode= 'nullable'),
      SchemaField(name= 'url', type= 'string', mode= 'nullable'),
      SchemaField(name= 'categorie', type= 'string', mode= 'nullable'),
     SchemaField(name= 'date', type= 'string', mode= 'nullable'),
     SchemaField(name='name', type= 'string', mode= 'nullable'),

]


table.create()
```

I have a :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-30edba459053> in <module>()
     23 
     24 table.schema = [
---> 25      SchemaField(name= 'id', type= 'int', mode= 'nullable'),
     26      SchemaField(name= 'zip', type= 'string', mode= 'nullable'),
     27      SchemaField(name= 'html', type= 'string', mode= 'nullable'),

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'
```

And i don't understand why SchemaField need a type for initialisation ...

If anyone have an idea

Thanks and regards

edit :

Even @andre622 don't work :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f177aa490fbb> in <module>()
     29   SchemaField('categorie', 'STRING', mode= 'nullable'),
     30  SchemaField('date', 'STRING', mode= 'nullable'),
---> 31  SchemaField('name', 'STRING', mode= 'nullable'),
     32 ]
     33 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py in schema(self, value)
    113         """
    114         if not all(isinstance(field, SchemaField) for field in value):
--> 115             raise ValueError('Schema items must be fields')
    116         self._schema = tuple(value)
    117 

ValueError: Schema items must be fields
```

Even with nick suggestion :

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
from gcloud.bigquery import SchemaField
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "toto.json"
os.environ['GCLOUD_PROJECT'] = 'titi'
from gcloud import pubsub

client = pubsub.Client('titi')

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Instantiates a client
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

# The name for the new dataset
dataset_name = 'choual'

# Prepares the new dataset
dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
table = dataset.table(name='aspire_page')

table.schema = [
     SchemaField('id','INTEGER'),
     SchemaField('zip', 'STRING'),
     SchemaField('html', 'STRING'),
     SchemaField('url', 'STRING'),
     SchemaField('categorie', 'STRING'),
     SchemaField('date', 'STRING'),
     SchemaField('name', 'STRING')
]


table.create()
```

i got this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-191573ca7711> in <module>()
     29      SchemaField('categorie', 'STRING'),
     30      SchemaField('date', 'STRING'),
---> 31      SchemaField('name', 'STRING')
     32 ]
     33 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py in schema(self, value)
    113         """
    114         if not all(isinstance(field, SchemaField) for field in value):
--> 115             raise ValueError('Schema items must be fields')
    116         self._schema = tuple(value)
    117 

ValueError: Schema items must be fields
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/schema.py) source, SchemaField does not take a `type`, it takes a `field_type`, this is what caused your error before @andre622's suggestion:

(Note that I did not write the following code.  All code belongs to Google Inc. under the Apache 2 license)

```
"""Describe a single field within a table schema.
:type name: str
:param name: the name of the field.
:type field_type: str
:param field_type: the type of the field (one of 'STRING', 'INTEGER',
                       'FLOAT', 'BOOLEAN', 'TIMESTAMP' or 'RECORD').
:type mode: str
:param mode: the type of the field (one of 'NULLABLE', 'REQUIRED',
                 or 'REPEATED').
:type description: str
:param description: optional description for the field.
:type fields: list of :class:`SchemaField`, or None
:param fields: subfields (requires ``field_type`` of 'RECORD').
"""
def __init__(self, name, field_type, mode='NULLABLE', description=None,
             fields=None):
    self.name = name
    self.field_type = field_type
    self.mode = mode
    self.description = description
    self.fields = fields
```

As you are using the default mode you should be able to use:

```
table.schema = [
     SchemaField('id','INTEGER'),
     SchemaField('zip', 'STRING'),
     SchemaField('html', 'STRING'),
     SchemaField('url', 'STRING'),
     SchemaField('categorie', 'STRING'),
     SchemaField('date', 'STRING'),
     SchemaField('name', 'STRING')
]
```

As for why it needs a type, how else would it know what type of data you want to store in that field, in DBMSs this allows correct allocation of space for each field as a row will take up a specific number of bytes.  This then allows for random access by knowing where the first row is and how big each row is.

EDIT:

Can you try instead:

```
table = dataset.table('aspire_page', [
         SchemaField('id','INTEGER'),
         SchemaField('zip', 'STRING'),
         SchemaField('html', 'STRING'),
         SchemaField('url', 'STRING'),
         SchemaField('categorie', 'STRING'),
         SchemaField('date', 'STRING'),
         SchemaField('name', 'STRING')
    ])
```

Also try with `bigquery.SchemaField` instead of just `SchemaField`, you may be having name clashes after importing `SchemaField` from `gcloud.bigquery` and from `google.cloud.bigquery`.

Comment: i've tried with your suggestion and edited my question and nope don't work thanks for your time :)

Comment: This code gives us: TypeError: table() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) How do we fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to give the keys for the first two key-value pairs you are passing to the table definition. Also, your data type definitions should follow how BigQuery needs to ingest them. Your schema should be defined like

```
table.schema = [
 SchemaField('id', 'INTEGER', mode= 'nullable'),
 SchemaField('zip', 'STRING', mode= 'nullable'),
 SchemaField('html', 'STRING', mode= 'nullable'),
  SchemaField('url', 'STRING', mode= 'nullable'),
  SchemaField('categorie', 'STRING', mode= 'nullable'),
 SchemaField('date', 'STRING', mode= 'nullable'),
 SchemaField('name', 'STRING', mode= 'nullable'),
]
```